# Сумма элементов на главной диагонали

Tags: visual-basic

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Начинаю изучать Visual Basic, нужно написать программу:

**Задание.**

Задан массив **m×m**.

Найти сумму элементов на главной диагонали (в матрице) и произведение элементов на побочной диагонали (в матрице).

Я создал проект, создал форму, куда ввожу размерности матрицы. Затем, есть кнопка. По нажатии на кнопку хотелось бы, чтобы открывалась форма с сеткой заданного размера, в которую можно вводить элементы матрицы, нажимать "Ок", и чтобы при нажатии появлялась форма с посчитанными значениями.

1. Как вводить матрицу (есть ли специальный Control)?
2. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку старая форма закрывалась, а новая открывалась?

Comment: в чем проблема?

Comment: @Grundy, отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: что вы используете: WinForms, WPF, еще что-нибудь?

Comment: @Grundy, Windows Forms

Comment: тогда смотрите: [_DataGridView_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e0ywh3cz(v=vs.110).aspx) - это контрол как раз и представляет таблицу

Comment: @Grundy, но это не решает проблему переключения между формами...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32555/discussion-between-grundy-and-neo).